# How to merge two for loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I have two for loops that I need combining.  I've spent a good hour or so on this.
I've tried making one into a function and adding into the other, but cannot crack it...

Array:

```
stooges = [('Curly',35,'New York'),('Larry',33,'Pennsylvania'),('Moe',40,'New York')]
```

First Loop:

```
for item in stooges:
    print ("Stooge: {0} {2} {1} ".format(item[0],item[1],item[2]))
```

Second Loop:

```
for i, val in enumerate(stooges, start=1):
    print ("Stooge", + i)
```

The output format I need is this:

```
Stooge 1: Curly New York 35 
Stooge 2: Larry Pennsylvania 33
Stooge 3: Moe New York 40
```

The closest I've come to is:

```
for i, val in enumerate(stooges, start=1):
    for item in stooges:
        print ("Stooge", + i, "{0} {2} {1} ".format(item[0],item[1],item[2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> for i, (name, age, city) in enumerate(stooges, start=1):
...     print("Stooge {}: {} {} {}".format(i, name, age, city))
Stooge 1: Curly 35 New York
Stooge 2: Larry 33 Pennsylvania
Stooge 3: Moe 40 New York
```

Comment: I put back the `start=` keyword name from the OP's original code, because I think it will be clearer to him (and maybe even to future readers) that way. But otherwise, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two for loops for that.

```
for index, stooge in enumerate(stooges, start=1):
    name, age, city = stooge
    print 'Stooge %d: %s %s %d' % (index, name, city, age)
```

Comment: But you _do_ need the `start=1` for that… Otherwise, `Curly` is stooge 0, which isn't the desired output.

Comment: Also, why would you suggest switching from `{}` formatting to `%` formatting?

Comment: @abarnert That's right. Thank you. What's wrong with switching from `{}` to `%`?

Comment: If the OP has working code that he wrote and understands, why give him different code to do the same thing, with no explanation? Why not just fix the broken part of his code, and leave the rest alone?

Comment: `format` is the recommended formatting operation for new code. Use of `%` is discouraged for new code.

Comment: @IonutHulub: So nobody can learn from your code unless they also learn to use the old-fashioned way of doing things? Why?

Comment: I did show his how to parse the data. He may print it either way he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, (n, a, c) in enumerate(stooges):
    print 'Stooge %d: %s %s %d' % (i + 1, n, c, a)

Stooge 1: Curly New York 35
Stooge 2: Larry Pennsylvania 33
Stooge 3: Moe New York 40
```